# How to Make a thumbnail from a online streaming mp4 video

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, video

I am trying to see if it is possible to make a thumbnail picture from an online video programmatically. Just to elaborate on what I am exactly looking to do: I have a link to to a video that plays in a browser using adobe flash. I would like to take a screenshot of the video (at any frame would do for now) using any programming language (prefer Mvc 4.0 ajax or js). Also I have noticed that when one uploads a video on youtube, it automatically generates a thumbnail. Any pointers as to if this is a viable option and how to go about it?

Thanks

Comment: you should have to access frame of Video on particular time

Comment: Read this . [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)